# Is it possible to hide Facebook app activity, so "X friends used it in the past month" doesn't show on hover?

Tags: facebook, stream, privacy

Facebook gives app developers control over whether app activity is published in the stream. Is it also possible to prevent the hover popup from showing friends who have used an app?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a few things:
If you have a canvas app, turn off "Social Discovery":
1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps and select your app.
2. Click "Edit Settings".
3. Click "Advanced" on the left.
4. Scroll down to Canvas Settings and set "Social Discovery" to "Disabled". This is designed to turn off news feed stories like "John used GreatApp." Maybe it turns off the feature you're describing, too. I haven't tested this.

When you are authenticating your users:
Set the default privacy controls to "Only Me". This makes it so any story published from your app has the most restrictive privacy settings possible by default. The user is allowed to edit this on their own, but most will leave it at the default. I don't know if this turns off the facepile on app hovercards, but you can test it to see.

Let me know if either of these works and we can edit the response to describe the correct solution!

Comment: Vin, thanks for the thorough response! Unfortunately I've done both of these things and neither turned off the prompt (which you can see by referencing an app you've installed in a comment e.g. @Klout and hovering over the resulting link). Any other ideas?

Comment: Not that I can think of. Why exactly are you trying to avoid having the friends facepile appear when the app link is displayed on Facebook? Is it for privacy reasons (i.e. an app which people may not want to publicly reveal they've used)? Or something else?

Comment: Mainly for privacy reasons. Also just curious whether this is possible.

Comment: OK. Sorry I don't have anything else helpful to offer then. I'm sure you have your reasons, but - if you don't think users would want to involve their friends at all, you might want to consider not making your app connect with Facebook at all. Whatever you do though, good luck!